# the result of using modulo in my java code is not correct why?

Tags: java

this is my code, when I enter 25000 the result being (25000=1,5000=1) while it must be only 25000=1, but if I enter 50,000 the result correct 50,000=2 but only for 25000 is wrong I don't know why it is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Mawa{

public static void main(String[]a){

int bestwpenj,da,penj,num;

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter a number");

System.out.println();

num=input.nextInt();


    bestwpenj=num/25000;

    da=(num%25000)/10000;

    penj=(num%10000)/5000;


System.out.println("25000= "+bestwpenj+"\n"+"10000= "+da+"\n"+"5000= "+penj);

}}
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: 25,000 modulo 10,000 is 5000. Dividing that by 5000 would yield `penj==1`. Why did you expect a different result?

Comment: it is wrong because 25000%25000 it must be only bestwpenj=1 not 5000=1, when I enter 50,000 its correct 50,000 contain only 2 of 25000

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. 25000%25000 would be 0, because 25000/25000 equals exactly 1. 25000%10000 is 5000, because 25000/10000 yields the integer value 2 with a remainder of 5000. If you didn't want `penj` to be 1, you're performing the wrong computation and need to reconsider what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Mawa{

public static void main(String[]a){

int bestwpenj,da,penj,num;

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter a number");

System.out.println();

num=input.nextInt();


    bestwpenj=num/25000;

    da=(num%25000)/10000;

    penj=(num%25000%10000)/5000;


System.out.println("25000= "+bestwpenj+"\n"+"10000= "+da+"\n"+"5000= "+penj);

}}
```

Comment: yes I mean this thanks very very much.